# The limit of $(1 - x^\alpha)^x $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: limits

I am trying to find the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ (x is an integer not a continuous variable) of the following

$(1 - x^\alpha)^x $

knowing that $0 < \alpha < 1$. Mathematica tells me its limit is 0 but cannot find a way by hand. my attempt involves writing the formula as a binomial expansion but I get the limit is 1 ...

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Please show how you got one as limit.

Comment: clearly the limit does not exist as it will tend to negative infinity for odd $x$ and to positive infinity if $x$ is even

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Thanks, I missed that... we ought to outlaw the use of $x$ as a discrete variable :)

Answer (score 2):

If $x > 1$ then $x^\alpha > 1$ and $1-x^\alpha < 0$ so that $(1-x^\alpha)^x$ changes sign as $x$ is even or odd.

Moreover $|1-x^\alpha|^x \ge |1-x^\alpha| = x^\alpha - 1$ for all $x \ge 1$. Since $x^\alpha \to \infty$ you conclude your sequence diverges rather badly.

Comment: @Clayton Of course, of course. Please forget my complaint.